# Submit jar in pyspark programmatically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-launcher

I'm from JVM world, and trying to find any analog of [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html) class available for Java and Scala distributions, but for Python and pyspark.
I want to submit jar file via python code programmatically.